# AngularJS - Select pierde tamaño si le saco el focus

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el un select armado con la herramienta oi-select que funciona bien, me muestra los productos y todo, pero cuando hago click en otro lado que no sea el select se me achica hasta casi desaparecer, adjunto una imagen de ejemplo:
[image: select achicado]

```
<oi-select 
  oi-options="producto as (producto.producto + ' - ' + producto.descripcion) for producto in productos track by producto.id"
  ng-model="producto" 
  placeholder="Seleccione un producto"
  ng-change="agregarProducto(producto)"
  >
</oi-select>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Falta el código en tu pregunta para ver que es lo que está fallando

Comment: Tenes razón! Me lo había olvidado! Ahí lo agregue =) @PauloUrbanoRivera